# Rails filters out json body with 4xx status code in test and production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

In my `api/posts_controller.rb`, I have this code:

```
def create
  if invalid?
    render status: 422, json: {message: 'this post is invalid'}
    return
  end

  @post = Post.create!(post_params)
  render 'api/posts/show'
end
```

If the post is invalid, it renders a json error message in development, but in test and production, the body is removed, and only the status code remains.

Comment: This is weird - I'm using same in production, and everything works fine. Could you post here your response (from Chrome Web Inspector, for example)? Also, which web-server are you using?

Comment: I'm starting to think it's not a Rails problem, but rather a browser issue. If I export the request (with the Chrome inspector) to cURL and import it in Postman, I get a response, but in Chrome I see "Failed to load response data"

Comment: I still have no clue why that happened, but it doesn't happen anymore.

Comment: You are welcome :D